# Java generics redefinition inside class function

Tags: java, generics

I have a class, intended to implement a generic Heap, and I'm having an issue with the generics I'm using. The class definition is
 `public class BinHeap <T extends Comparable<? super T>> {`

Within the class, I have a function to delete the smallest value from the heap (It's unfinished due to the error I'm getting).

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T deleteMin() {
  T returnVal = (T)arr[0];
  T temp = (T)arr[num-1];
  num--;
  int hole = 0;
  int ret = -1;
  int newhole = newHole(hole,temp);

  return null;
}
```

This function calls newHole, which is defined here

```
private int newHole(int hole, T item) {
  int ret = -1;
  if(1+(hole*2) < num+1) {
     if(2+(hole*2) == num+1) {
        if(arr[1+(hole*2)].compareTo(item) == -1) {
           ret = 1+(hole*2);
        }
     }
     else {
        int smallerChild;
        int smaller = arr[1+(hole*2)].compareTo(arr[2+(hole*2)]);
        if(smaller == -1) {
           smallerChild = 1+(hole*2);
        }
        else {
           smallerChild = 2+(hole*2);
        }
        if(arr[smallerChild].compareTo(arr[hole]) == -1) {
           ret = smallerChild;
        }
     }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

When I test compile, I get the following error

```
BinHeap.java:51: error: method newHole in class BinHeap<T#1> cannot be applied to given types;
  int newhole = newHole(hole,temp);
                ^
required: int,T#1
found: int,T#2
reason: actual argument T#2 cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in class BinHeap
T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2> declared in method <T#2>deleteMin()
```

While I do understand what the compiler is telling me, I have no idea how exactly to fix the issue. How can I make the `T temp = (T)arr[num-1];` of the correct generic type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only define `T` on the class.  Currently, you are defining a second `T` on the method, which hides the `T` on the class.  You can simply refer to `T` in the method, when you remove the re-definition of `T` on the method.

```
public T deleteMin() {  // T is already in scope
```